# Problems with Listview in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I already managed to implement a ViewPager inside a fragment, filled with listviews on each tab. If you click on an item from one of the listviews, a new fragment should fill the whole screen to show some details of the selected item. The problem is, that the new fragment isn't showing anything. It's just empty and so frustrating!

VerlaufFragment.java, holding the viewPager

```
public class VerlaufFragment extends Fragment {

public static ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_main, container, false);
        // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        // Set the ViewPagerAdapter into ViewPager
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
        return view;
    }

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    // Declare the number of ViewPager pages
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 7;
    private String titles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2" , "Tab3" , "Tab4" ,        "Tab5" , "Tab6" , "Tab7" };

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            // Open FragmentTab1
        case 0:
            UebungenMainFragment fragmenttab1 = new UebungenMainFragment();
            return fragmenttab1;
            // Open FragmentTab2
        case 1:
            UebungenMainFragment fragmenttab2 = new UebungenMainFragment();
            return fragmenttab2;
            //Open FragmentTab3
        default:
            UebungenMainFragment fragmenttab3 = new UebungenMainFragment();
            return fragmenttab3;
        }
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

}

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

}
```

UebungenMainFragment.java with all the Listviews

```
public class UebungenMainFragment extends ListFragment {

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Item", "Item", "Item",
    "Item", "Item", "Item", "Item", "Item",
    "Item", "Item", "Item", "Item", "Item", "Item"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId(), new UebungDetailedFragment());
  transaction.addToBackStack(null);
  transaction.commit();
  }
}
```

and finally the UebungDetailedFragment.java with details of the item

```
public class UebungDetailedFragment extends Fragment{
    TextView tvItemName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
            false);

    tvItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag1_text);

    tvItemName.setText("HELLO WORLD");
    return view;
}
}
```

xml Files:

fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/frag1_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If I click on one of the items, the tabs are still visible, the listview is gone, but my "HELLO WORLD" doesn't appear. Also if I stay in this "empty" view and swipe horizontaly, I can still swipe between the listviews, what I also don't want. Any idea to make it works?

Comment: Are you sure that `((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId()` gives a valid ID?

Comment: Thank you for your time :) I did so, because nothing else worked in this line. I also tried it with R.ID.viewpager, R.ID.content_frame. How can i test that to get the right ID?

Comment: Still I didn't get it running :(

Comment: Your viewpager isn't able to calculate height!